# Finding general formula for $\cos^{-1}({\cos{x})}$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

My teacher teacher told me that for a general angle $x$, $\cos^{-1}({\cos{x})}$ does't represent $x$ but different straight lines depending upon the intervals in which it lies. For ex:

$$\cos^{-1}{\cos{x}}=$$
$$x,0\leq x \leq \pi \\ 2\pi-x,\pi\leq x \leq 2\pi\\…$$
making the graph look like :-
[From wolfram alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWn8x.gif)

He told us that if we have to find the value of $\cos^{-1}({\cos{x})}$ for a particular $x$ we will have to first find the range in which $x$ lies and then judge with the help of graph but I wondered if there is a direct formula for that. I tried with $\tan^-1({\tan{x}})$ and got it as :-
[from wolfram alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ88J.jpg)

I even verified this with wolfram alpha and got it right but the problem with $\cos$ is that when I try to solve it similarly like I did with the $\tan$ one, and get the interval in which $n$ lies, the extremities of the interval differ by $0.5$ because of which for some values their floor and ceiling match but for some values there isn't an integer value lying in that interval like this :- [from wolfram alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1T3i.gif)

so what to do in that case and what does no value of $n$ lying in the interval signify?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: $\cos ^{-1} \cos x=t ⇒  t=2k\pi+x, k∈   N $

Comment: How to find the 'k'? Thanks

Comment: I think k could be any number in N.

Comment: But that would mean that the function is having more than one value for a single value of x

Comment: we can't find a "formula" for it, we always need to divide in two pieces since it is decribed by two different formulas.

Comment: Yep. I got it now. Thanks :)

Comment: $\cos ^{-1}(\cos (x))=\\\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{20} i e^{-i \left(-\frac{\pi }{2}+x\right)} \pi  \left(-\Phi \left(-e^{-2 i \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)},2,\frac{1}{2}\right)+e^{2 i \left(-\frac{\pi }{2}+x\right)} \Phi \left(-e^{2 i \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)},2,\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$         . where  $\Phi (x,a,b)$  is  Lerch transcendent function.

Comment: Thanks! but thas too complex to learn and apply in competitive exams but it's great!

Comment: Simpler by `mod` and `abs` function: $\cos ^{-1}(\cos (x))=2 \left|-\frac{\pi }{2}+(\frac{\pi +x}{2} \bmod \pi )\right|$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, thanks! Thats a great help. Could you just help a little more by telling the source from where you read this? Thanks a lot again! I would just like to add an another form of your formula, ie abs(x - 2 pi floor((pi + x)/(2 pi)))

Comment: Source from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition we have that for $x\in[0,2\pi]$

- for $0\le x\le \pi\quad $ $\cos^{-1}{\cos{x}}=x$
- for $\pi<x\le 2\pi\quad$ $\cos^{-1}{\cos{x}}=2\pi-x$

and this is periodic with period $T=2\pi$.

Thus it is a kind of [triangle function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleFunction.html) and we always need to divide into two parts dependind upon the range in which x lies.

Comment: @mayankmittal ops sorry I lost this part, thus you are looking for another expression?

Comment: No I got it, Thanks for help. I had been toiling around it for an hour. Thanks :)

Comment: @mayankmittal You are welcome and You already had clear the general set upo for the solution that's important since often we can get confused with this kind of expression. Iìm sorry there is not such kind of formula! Bye

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing $\arccos$ instead of $\cos^{-1}$. By definition,
$$\arccos(\cos y)=y\qquad(0\leq y\leq\pi)\ .$$
For arbitrary $x\in{\mathbb R}$ define
$$d(x):=\min\bigl\{|x-2k\pi|\,\bigm|\,k\in{\mathbb Z}\bigr\}$$
to be the distance of $x$ from the nearest integer multiple of $2\pi$. Then
$$0\leq d(x)\leq\pi,\quad \cos x=\cos\bigl(d(x)\bigr)\qquad\forall x\in{\mathbb R}\ .$$
It follows that
$$\arccos(\cos x)=\arccos\bigl(\cos\bigr(d(x)\bigr)\bigr)=d(x)\qquad(x\in{\mathbb R})\ ,$$
which reveals $\arccos\circ\cos$ to be a sawtooth function.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim.** *Let $x\in\left[k\pi,\left(k+1\right)\pi\right]$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then:*

\begin{alignat*}{1}
\cos^{-1}\left(\cos x\right) & =\begin{cases}
x-k\pi & \textit{if }k\textit{ is even},\\
\left(k+1\right)\pi-x & \textit{if }k\textit{ is odd}.
\end{cases}
\end{alignat*}

---

*Proof.* First, note that $x-k\pi$ and $\left(k+1\right)\pi-x$ are both in  $\left[0,\pi\right]$.

Moreover, if $y\in\left[0,\pi\right]$, then $\cos^{-1}\left(\cos y\right)\overset{1}{=}y$.

Now, suppose $k$ is even. Then $\cos\left(x-k\pi\right) \overset{2}{=}\cos x$ and so:

$$\cos^{-1}\left(\cos x\right)=\cos^{-1}\left[\cos\left(x-k\pi\right)\right]\overset{1}{=}x-k\pi.$$

Next, suppose $k$ is odd. Then $\cos\left[\left(k+1\right)\pi-x\right]\overset{3}{=}\cos x$ and so:

$$\cos^{-1}\left(\cos x\right)=\cos^{-1}\left[\cos\left(\left(k+1\right)\pi-x\right)\right]\overset{1}{=}\left(k+1\right)\pi-x. \tag*{∎}$$

---

(The reader can verify $\overset{2}{=}$ and $\overset{3}{=}$ using the [Subtraction Formulae for Cosine](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html).)